# how to bind a form with jQgrid?

Tags: jquery, forms, binding, jqgrid

I have a form with 3 text field and 2 combobox...I have send those data to server based on which my jqGrid will be populated...I can append the parameter like &text1=&text2& etc.  Can someone point me towards an example based on binding form with jqGrid. 
Thanks!

**UPdate1:**
my approach

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     var url = "/cpsb/inventoryInquiry.do?method=getInventoryDetails" + $("#inventoryForm").serialize();

    navMenu();

  jQuery("#inventoryInq").jqGrid({
                    sortable:true,
                    url: '',
                    datatype:'json',
                 colNames:['LPN','SKU', 'Location Description', 'Location Type','Pallet Status','On Hand Quantity', 'Inducted Quantity','Rejected Qty','Hold?','Expiration Date' ], 
                 colModel:[  {name:'lpn',index:'lpn', width:85, sorttype:"int", align:"center", key:true},
                             {name:'sku',index:'sku', width:40, sorttype:"int", align:"center"},
                             {name:'locationDescription',index:'locationDescription', width:130, align:"center"},
                             {name:'locationType',index:'locationType', width:100, align:"center"}, 
                             {name:'palletStatus',index:'palletStatus', width:80, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                             {name:'onHandQuantity', index:'onHandQuantity',width:130, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                             {name:'inductedQuantity', index:'inductedQuantity', width:115, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                             {name:'rejectedQuantity', index:'rejectedQuantity', width:120, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                             {name:'hold',index:'hold', width:60,align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                             {name:'expirationDate', index:'expirationDate',width:120, align:"center"} ],

               rowNum:10,
               rowList:[10,20,30],
               jsonReader : {repeatitems: false,
                    root: function(obj) {
                        return obj;
                    },
                    page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                    total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                    records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
                },
               pager: '#pager',
               sortname: 'LPN',
               sortorder: "desc",
               loadonce:true,
               viewrecords: true,
               multiselect: true,
               caption: "Inventory Inquiry",
               height:230 
             }); 
          jQuery("#inventoryInq").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{view:true,add:false,edit:false,del:false, searchtext:'Filter'},{},{},{},{multipleSearch:true});
         jQuery("#inventoryInq").jqGrid('hideCol', 'cb');


  }) ;   

  $("form#inventoryForm").submit(function() {
        var newUrl = "/cpsb/inventoryInquiry.do?method=getInventoryDetails" + $(this).serialize();
        $("#inventoryInq").jqGrid("setGridParam","url", url).trigger("reloadGrid");
        return false;
    });


//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: It seems to me that you should add '&' after `?method=getInventoryDetails` in both places (`var url` and `var newUrl`).

Comment: Thanks! but when I am using $("#inventoryForm").serialize()..doesn't it append &?

Comment: Look at the example from http://api.jquery.com/serialize/. `$.serialize()` build the string like `a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5` and **not** the string `&a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5`. So you if you manually construct `url` you have to add '&' after `?method=getInventoryDetails`. If you use both `url` **and** `postData` like `$("#inventoryInq").jqGrid("setGridParam", {url: "/cpsb/inventoryInquiry.do?method=getInventoryDetails", postData: $(this).serialize()})` then `jQuery` receive two separate parameter and it make concatenation. So `jQuery` are able to include '&' between.

Comment: By the way in you current code inside of `$("form#inventoryForm").submit` there are a small error: instead of `$("#inventoryInq").jqGrid("setGridParam","url", url)` you should write `$("#inventoryInq").jqGrid("setGridParam",{"url": url})` or `$("#inventoryInq").jqGrid("setGridParam",{url: url})`

Comment: @Oleg Thanks! I have one more issue when I am  sending data with no values inserted it is sending null instead of blank ...using .serialize()...is there a work around to send blank instead of null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general suggestion of JacobM is good, but there are some details.

First the textes `text1` and `text2` could contain a special symbols which are not allows in URL, so they should be better url-encoded and instead of `+ text1 + "&text2=" + text2` one should better use `+ encodeURIComponent(text1) + "&text2=" + encodeURIComponent(text2)`. The jQuery function [jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) do this internaly, so instead of

```
var url = "http://www.mySite.com/gridRequestURL?text1=" + text1 + "&text2=" + text2;
```

we can use

```
var url="http://www.mySite.com/gridRequestURL?"+$.param({text1:text1, text2:text2});
```

Moreover jQuery has one more nice function to make encoding of **all input fields** (input and select fields and checkboxes) of one form: [jQuery.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). If you choose the names of the form parameters exactly like you want to have server parameters, then the new url can be just

```
var url = "http://www.mySite.com/gridRequestURL?" + $("#fpForm").serialize();
```

(where "fpForm" is id of the form) and the full code could looks like following

```
$("form#fpForm").submit(function() {
    var newUrl = "/cpsb/cPSBBusinessErrors.do?" + $(this).serialize();
    $("#gridId").jqGrid("setGridParam","url", url).trigger("reloadGrid");
    return false;
}
```

Take in consideration that, if you use `postData` parameter of jqGrid, the url will be automatically appended with the information from `postData` (target url will be combined from `url` and `postData`).

You can also consider to use only `postData` parameter, but as a function as described in [How to filter the jqGrid data NOT using the built in search/filter box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819), then you should use only `trigger("reloadGrid")` without changing of `url`. The login of reading values from the form fields you should implement in the functions from `postData`.

If you use HTTP POST (`mtype: "POST"`) and not default GET you can set `postData` parameter with the same information as described above instead of appending the information to the `url` parameter.

Comment: Thanks! @Oleg ...I will try to follow your suggestion .

Comment: I have updated my question with your approach...can I do like that?